# Merging MVC in Webforms produces slow performance and redirects to login page in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, webforms

For an undefined reason when I tried to integrate MVC5 in a webforms app it works fine after adding routes ignores in global.asax on my machine, but in production seems the Session is null because it redirects to login.aspx after getting 302 from default.aspx.

Obvious issue:

1. Slow response.(~ 11.84 s)
2. Problem of Session.

   ```
       public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
       //ignore aspx pages (web forms take care of these)
       //routes.Add(new Route("favicon.ico", new StopRoutingHandler()));
       routes.MapPageRoute("default", "", "~/default.aspx");
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathInfo}", new { folder = "Services" });
       //routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" }); 
       routes.MapRoute(
           // Route name
           "home",
           // URL with parameters
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           // Parameter defaults
           new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = "" }
           );
   }
   ```

Web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
  <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
</staticContent>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules  runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  <remove name="Session" />
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in you web.config file, check if it contains the following in you production environment.

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <modules>
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
      ...
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Same result @peer, redirects to default.aspx then to login.aspx.(monitored by chrome developer tool)

Answer (score 0):

A late response, but I'm going to post it anyway. The setting:

```
runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"
```

Can have big impact in performance, e.g. on the time that images have to load. In your browser you can analyse the network activity and compare times of image and script loads with this setting set to true and false.